# loadFFromJSON fabric.js draws the canvas but does not set the objects

Tags: fabricjs

I load the canvas by

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(templates[templateInd].contents, setCanvasAgain);
```

where setCanvasAgain loops through the objects on canvas to set some new properties. In the end of the function I call `canvas.renderAll()`

```
function setCanvasAgain() {
    canvas.forEachObject(function(object) {
        //var customPosition = canvas._objects[i].customPosition;
        var customPosition = object.customPosition;
        if (customPosition == 'content-header') {
            console.log('templates[templateInd].catPictoHeader:');
            console.log(templates[templateInd].catPictoHeader);
            // addPictoLine(position,count,categoryArray){
            header += addPictoLine(customPosition, templates[templateInd].pictoInputsHeader, templates[templateInd].catPictoHeader);
            //pictoCount++;
        } else if (customPosition == 'content-body') {
            if (object.type == 'text') {
                //addTextLine params: textCount,arrayLength
                body += addTextLine(textCount, templates[templateInd].textInputs);
                textCount++;
            } else if (object.label == 'picto') {
                body += addPictoLine(customPosition, templates[templateInd].pictoInputsBody, templates[templateInd].catPictoBody);
                //pictoCount++;
            } else if (object.label == 'verkeersteken') {
                body += addPictoLine(customPosition, templates[templateInd].vtknInputsBody, templates[templateInd].catVtknBody);
            }
        } else if (customPosition == 'content-footer') {
            footer += addPictoLine(customPosition, templates[templateInd].pictoInputsFooter, templates[templateInd].catPictoFooter);
            //pictoCount++;
        }
        addControlBtn(object, customPosition);
        //  //console.log(i);
        object.set({
            lockMovementX: true,
            lockMovementY: true,
            hasControls: false
        });
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

But when it is done and I try to set the canvas to SVG it appears blank. If I try to look into the canvas, there are also no objects there (so nothing to be drawn). It looks like that the json content is not binding with canvas...
I have also tried the classic

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(templates[templateInd].contents, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
```

But with the same result. So how do I get the objects from JSON get bind with the canvas /to be set as objects of the canvas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have come across one more issue: 
The  templates[templateInd].contents contains the stringified canvas. The objects of have custom properties set by fabric.util.object.extend. In stringified canvas these custom properties appear just fine. But when I add stringified objects to the canvas the custom properties just dissapear... Or should I put it in a separate question?

Comment: If additional property are in json , then it will load properly. Show the code, how you are converting canvas to svg?

Comment: And yet it is not. Currently I have solved the problem by adding the custom properties toObject constructor in the setCanvasAgain function. just by extendObject(object), the function by which I set the custom properties in the first place, which is just copied from the fabrics tutorials page. So I call it once more. Also calling the toSVG inside the setCanvasAgain function solves the problem with svg. (I'm converting canvas to svg with canvas.toSVG()) But yet I don't understand why just  simply canvas.loadFromJSON(templates[templateInd].contents) does not set the canvas right away...